# Файл базаы данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Написал простенький сайт php+mysql. Захотел закинуть на сайт портфолио и тут возник вопрос. Собственно куда файл бд то закинуть, и как он до этого подключался?
Бд написал с помощью консоли xampp. Подключил вот так хотя и не понял откуда он его берет.

```
    <?php 

$driver = 'mysql';
$host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'dynweb';
$db_user = 'admin';
$db_pass = '123';
$charset = 'utf8';
$options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

try{
    $pdo = new
    PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset", $db_user, $db_pass, $options);
    if(isset($_COOKIE["page_visit"])) {
 $_COOKIE["page_visit"]
        setcookie('page_visit' , ++$_COOKIE["page_visit"] , time()+86400);
    } else {
        setcookie('page_visit' , 1 , time() + 86400);
        $_COOKIE['page_visit'] = 1;
    }
    session_start();
} catch(PDOException $e) { 
    die('не могу подключится к базе данных');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Оперировать файлом/файлами базы данных напрямую приходится **очень редко**.

Для доступа к БД хостинг-провайдер выдает вам пароль/логин. Их вы используете в своем скрипте для подключения к БД.

Для того чтобы заполнить БД какими-то предварительными данными используются разные подходы, но связанные, в основном, с экспортом/импортом sql-дампов баз данных.

Например, вы делаете у себя локально дамп вашей БД (получаете `.sql`-файл), на хостинг этот файл может попадать через какую-либо систему администрирования БД (*phpmyadmin*, *adminer* или какая-то конкретная система у хостинг-провайдера). 
Если у вас **шаред-хостинг**, то доступ в *phpmyadmin* обычно предоставляется провайдером, если **выделенный сервер** - то установкой *phpmyadmin* или чего-то подобного требуется озаботиться самому.

Также вы можете залить дамп вашей БД по ftp/sftp/ssh. Таким образом файл будет на сервере и вы можете его загрузить используя, например, командную строку mysql (при ssh-подключении).

Если совсем ничего вышеуказанного нет - то можно создать просто php-скрипт, выполняющий запросы на вставку в БД, залить его на сервер и единожды запустить.